# Bind SVG attributes to RxJS.Observable in Angular 2

Tags: angular, svg

I'm trying to bind an `Observable` to an SVG element

```
<svg width="500px" height="500px">
  <circle *ngFor="let point of points2 | async"
    [attr.cx]="point.x" 
    [attr.cy]="point.y"
    r=20 stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="#0080ff" />
</svg>
```

where `points2` is defined as

```
this.points2 = Observable.from([
  [{ x: 250, y: 50 },  {x: 200, y: 100 }]
]);
```

which actually works. However, the following example does not:

```
<svg width="500px" height="500px">
  <circle *ngFor="let point of points1 | async"
    [attr.cx]="point.x" 
    [attr.cy]="point.y"
    r=20 stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="#0080ff" />
</svg>
```

(same as before, just different variable name) with `points1`

```
this.points1 = new Subject<IPoint[]>();
this.getCoords();
```

and

```
getCoords() {
  let delay = 1000;

  setTimeout(() => {
    this.points1.next([{ x: 50, y: 50)}, { x: 100, y: 100 }]);
    this.points1.complete();
  }, delay);
}
```

By "doesn't work" I mean that the dots don't show up at all ([plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2doYepnym9IMPxAKjHXk?p=preview) showing the problem). In my production app they do show up, but they're stuck at `(0, 0)` even though the values look perfectly fine. So it would seem I'm missing something here.

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `)` at the wrong place!

`this.points1.next([{ x: 50, y: 50)<<<<<<<<<<<!!!!}, { x: 100, y: 100 }]);`